# java.io.IOException: Rethrown as IOE

Tags: java, jmeter, ioexception

While trying to hit a simple HTTPS web service (GET) request getting the below Java IO exception, but while I hit the same HTTPS URL on browser getting successful response. Also for the HTTP GET request it is working fine

```
 java.io.IOException: Rethrown as IOE
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:134)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:405)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:539)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.2 //(Forcibly set the TLS to TLSv1.2 rather than defaulting to SSLv3) SSLContext not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.createContext(JsseSSLManager.java:210)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.getContext(JsseSSLManager.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.getSSLSocketFactory(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:112)
```

Comment: What's your JMeter version?

Answer (score 1):

The version of `Java` your `JMeter` is using does not support TLSv1.2.

Check that.

Comment: Checked my java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode). Hope by default it supports the TLSv1.2